# What are the methods to create indices?

Tags: indexing, cassandra, titan, rexster

Every example I've been able to find in the Titan documentation creates indices using the Rexster console. You log in to a single Titan node, create your indices and commit. After a while the whole cluster is aware of the index and it can be used.

I am wondering if there are other ways to do this. There are some benefits when creating indices from code e.g. in a Rexster extension: I use ENUMs for property keys and edge labels that offer `toString` methods I can use on index creation. This way there is no worry about changed values.

Another aspect to mention is that I benchmark Titan and thus reinitialize the cluster quite often. It is more comfortable to let the code do all the work for me than logging in to a node and do it manually.

However, creating indices from code seems to be a mess and caused multiple exceptions when using an eventually-consistent storage backend. I think due to my simultaneous node startup multiple nodes tried to create the indices.
See [Titan node does not come up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28094341/titan-node-does-not-come-up) for details.

Is there a proper way of handling these issues? Are there further methods I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

In practice, I don't think many people create their schema by manually typing things into the console.  I typically create a `Schema` class that has some methods to do that work.  In that way, I can use enums, static string variables, etc. in the way you are describing.  That `Schema` class is really useful, because it represents a versioned instance of what my Titan schema looks like at any given time and I can re-use it in lots of places (to initialize a production instance manually, construct schema between unit tests, work it into a groovy script to use for automation on your build server, etc.)

For Titan, the `Schema` class is quite central to the concept of developing and maintaining a custom Gremlin DSL.  You may find this [blog post](http://thinkaurelius.com/2013/07/25/developing-a-domain-specific-language-in-gremlin/) on the topic interesting if you have not already read it.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on that? The blog post is indeed interesting but I can not figure out what language this class is written in or where to put it/how to use it. Is there any documentation on that?

Comment: I always write such code in Groovy as you would typically write traversals with it as well, however I don't see why you couldn't write it in any JVM language you choose, build a jar and depend on it as needed.

Comment: I hoped that there would be an initialization method that is executed once per graph creation. This would be the perfect point to create the schema. In all other cases one has to make sure the nodes don't try to create the schema simultaneously, which seem to had happened using Cassandra. One could create a Rexster extension `createGraphSchema` and makes sure it is called once but this seems overkill to me.

Comment: I don't know of such a method.  I've typically used the `Schema` class I've been talking about outside of code deployed to individual nodes, so that I don't run into such problems.  If you're trying to automate the startup and initialization of your cluster it would seem that as part of cassandra start up you could just call a groovy script that called the `Schema` class to do its work.  After that is done, fire up Rexster and whatever other applications you have running.  To me, schema definition is something best done outside of application code.